# How to use a controller for two directives?

Tags: angularjs

I have this code:

JS:

```js
angular.module("module")
  .controller("fooController", ["$scope", function($scope) {
    ...
  })
  .directive("foo", function() {
    return {
      restrict: "E",
      controller: "fooController",
      link: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
        // Do some things with the scope of the controller here
      }
    }
  })
  .directive("bar", function() {
    return {
      restrict: "E",
      require: "fooController",
      link: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
         // Nothing yet
      }
    }
  });
```

HTML:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- Scripts here -->
  </head>
  <body ng-app="module">
    <foo/>
    <bar/>
  </body>
</html>
```

Directive `foo` works, but directive `bar` throws an error: `No controller: fooController`.

How can I fix this while maintaining my current structure (Controller isn't inside the HTML, but is used by the directives, `bar` is outside `foo` and share the same controller, while both are modifying its scope)? I read the discussion [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/angular/dKDkMeF670E), but I couldn't understand how to do it.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, Why are you using the same controller for both the directives?

Comment: I need to share some data between them. Do you know a better way to do this?

Comment: Yes - Services! `$rootScope` too does the trick but will be frowned upon. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9293423/can-one-controller-call-another-in-angularjs - this is all that you need to know to communicate between controllers.

Comment: Great! Post it as an answer and I'll be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since your ultimate objective is to communicate between controllers, you need not re-use the same controller across multiple directives (I doubt if re-using would allow you to communicate). Anyway, the best way to go about it would be use services.

Article [Can one controller call another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9293423/can-one-controller-call-another-in-angularjs) speaks about it in detail, but in simple terms, first create a service:

```
app.factory('myService', function () {
    var data;
    return {
        getData: function () {
            return data
        },
        setData: function (newData) {
            data = newData;
        }
    };
});
```

You can then use this service in your controllers and communicate with each controller by using `setData()` and `getData()` functions of the service.

Answer (score 4):

You can't require a controller. You can require a directive which is one of the parents of the current directive.

```
   <foo>
      <bar />
   </foo>

   // in foo
   controller: 'fooController'
   // in bar
   require: '^foo' // ^ means to search it up in the tree
```

Here bar can require foo and it'll have foo's controller: http://jsfiddle.net/Zmetser/kHdVX/
In this example fooController'll be initialized once.

```
   <foo />
   <bar />

   // in foo
   controller: 'fooController'
   // in bar
   controller: 'fooController'
```

Here bar and foo has its on instance of the fooController: http://jsfiddle.net/Zmetser/QypXn/

Comment: But yeah, if your directives are siblings, services are a solution.

Comment: Good solution and I'll definitely use it when the directives don't have to be siblings. For this case, callmekatootie's is better IMHO.