# Is it possible to know which directive initialized my controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Let's say I have two directives:

```
angular.module('example').directive('dir1', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: true,
    controller: 'ExampleCtrl'
};});

angular.module('example').directive('dir2', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: true,
    controller: 'ExampleCtrl'
};});
```

Is it possible to tell which directive initialized `ExampleCtrl` inside this controller?

Comment: I suspect not (without some serious, case specific hacks), but hopefully I will be proven wrong!

Comment: I am interested in hacky solutions to this problem as well

Comment: Could you please also provide the rational for wanting to do this? Not to say there isn't a valid reason but perhaps there is a better way if we understand what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: why would you want to do that?

Comment: You could use a service instead of a controller. Take a look of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16935024/how-to-use-a-controller-for-two-directives

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
angular.module('example').directive('dir1', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: true,
    controller: 'ExampleCtrl',
    controllerAs: 'dir1Ctrl'
};});

angular.module('example').directive('dir2', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: true,
    controller: 'ExampleCtrl',
    controllerAs: 'dir2Ctrl'
};});
```

Then, in the controller, `$scope.dirNcontroller`, where `N` is 1 or 2 or as many as you have, will exist only if it came from directive `N`. This is how the `controllerAs` syntax works, it is simply published to the scope.

Something like this:

```
app.controller('ExampleCtrl', function($scope, $element) {
  if ($scope.dir1Ctrl) /* do something */
  if ($scope.dir2Ctrl) /* do something else */
});
```

[**PLUNKER**](http://plnkr.co/edit/0E8thapkVwjqCVhpONGO?p=preview)

Comment: Interesting approach, this solution might work for me

Answer (score 1):

I thought of 2 ways. This solution I find much less hacky, but is also less dynamic:

```
angular.module('example').directive('dir1', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: true,
    controller: 'ExampleCtrl',
    link: function(scope) {
      $scope.myDir="dir1";
    }
};});

angular.module('example').directive('dir2', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: true,
    controller: 'ExampleCtrl'
    link: function(scope) {
      $scope.myDir="dir2";
    }
};});
```

In this way you are baking the parent directive into the scope, which is available to the controller.

---

This solution is more hacky, but also more dynamic. Using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12960701/how-do-i-get-current-scope-dom-element-in-angularjs-controller) question, we can get our containing element:

```
function innerItem($scope, $element){
    var jQueryInnerItem = $($element); 
}
```

from there, we can test that element for attributes and properties that would be specific to one directive over another (such as directive name). I still think this is very hacky and you have an underlying issue (perhaps a bit of XY problem here), but this should work.

Comment: Your main solution will not work for me, because I need to identify directive in   controller initialization code and link is executed only after controller is initialized

Comment: @brisky Why do you need it during initialization? These requirements are getting a bit silly. You seem to have a bigger underlying problem with your design at this point.That being said, you can look into compile to get the values in pre-initialization... but again you really need to take a hard look at your design.

Comment: I don't want to post the exact problem that I am solving because I know there are easier ways to solve it. What I am trying to achieve with my current solution is better readability in my html templates by using directives with values as simple strings and not objects

Comment: @brisky These solutions are not going to improve readability... Just use your easier solution. Easier = simpler = better.