# How to share data between controllers in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I'm currently trying to learn angularJS and am having trouble accessing data between controllers.

My first controller pulls a list of currencies from my api and assigns it to $scope.currencies.  When I click edit, what is supposed to happen is that it switches the view which uses another controller.  now when debugging using batarang, $scope.currencies does show an array of currency objects:

```
{
    currencies: [{
        CurrencyCode: HKD
        Description: HONG KONG DOLLAR
        ExchangeRateModifier: * ExchangeRate: 1
        DecimalPlace: 2
    }, {
        CurrencyCode: USD
        Description: US DOLLAR
        ExchangeRateModifier: * ExchangeRate: 7.7
        DecimalPlace: 2
    }]
}
```

But when using `angular.copy`, the `$scope.copiedcurrencies` result in null.

```
function CurrencyEditCtrl($scope, $injector, $routeParams) {
    $injector.invoke(CurrencyCtrl, this, { $scope: $scope });
    $scope.copiedcurrencies = angular.copy($scope.currencies);
    console.log($scope.copiedcurrencies);
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can one controller call another in AngularJS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9293423/can-one-controller-call-another-in-angularjs)

Comment: Is my solution not helpful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most common and recommended method for sharing data between controllers is to use a service. [Click here for Live Demo (see app.js)](http://plnkr.co/edit/m7DaFqVvDxuJznijdt2q?p=preview)

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.factory('myService', function() {
  var myService = {
    foo: 'bar'
  };
  return myService;
});

app.controller('myCtrl1', function(myService) {
  console.log(myService.foo);
  myService.foo = 'not bar anymore!';
});

app.controller('myCtrl2', function(myService) {
  console.log(myService.foo);
});
```

Note: there are several ways of creating a service.