# angularjs access value of one controller from another

Tags: angularjs

```
<div ng-controller="aCtrl">
 <input type="text" ng-model="person" />
 <button type="button" ng-click="Search()">XXX</button>
</div>

<div ng-controller="bCtrl">
 <input type="text" ng-model="car" />
</div>
```

In the onclick event Search() how do I gain access to  $scope.car, which is inside another controller?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can one controller call another in AngularJS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9293423/can-one-controller-call-another-in-angularjs)

Comment: Not sure if you can..I know creating a shared service would be one way to go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a simple solution:

```
<div ng-init='model={ person: "", car: "" }'>
  <div ng-controller="aCtrl">
   <input type="text" ng-model="model.person" />
   <button type="button" ng-click="Search()">XXX</button>
  </div>

  <div ng-controller="bCtrl">
   <input type="text" ng-model="model.car" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Simply go one step higher on the `$scope` and set your data on the parent scope. Notice that I updated the values bound to your inputs to reference properties of the new `model` object. By doing this, you reference an *object* on that parent scope rather than *scalars*, so that the *reference* to that object gets prototypically inherited by the child scopes. If this doesn't make much sense, the tl;dr version is:

**Generally speaking, you want to make sure that your `ng-model` directives contain a dot.**

You could also define an angular *service* to share data between the two controllers, but that's possibly overkill for what you need.

Comment: I'd go with the service option, if you continue  using angular you will need to know how to do it, and it feels more natural to me at least. . .

Comment: Perhaps. Given the `ng-model` usage, I figured illustrating the necessity of the dot in `ng-model` was probably the most edifying to the OP. In AngularJS, like with anything, there exists a wide variety of feline hide removal techniques.

Comment: And how can I access that `model.person` from any controller's javascript?

Comment: @Arkanoid you might want to open a new question for that.