# angularjs: events not get delivered to controller which may not live at that time

Tags: events, angularjs, scope

I think this must be a very common problem, let's say the routes like

```
$routeProvider
        .when('/producer', {
            templateUrl: 'ui/producer.html',
            controller: 'ProducerCtrl'
        })
        .when('/consumer', {
            templateUrl: 'ui/consumer.html',
            controller: 'ConsumerCtrl'
        })
```

from my understanding of $scope life cycle, each time routing happens a new scope/controller is created and initialized, and old one dies. This causes at a given time there is either producer or consumer controller alive, but not both. I have observed this using angular Batarang. As a consequence, I am not able to send an event from producer to consumer, vice versa.

This is very consuming, as event is designed for communication between controllers. or it only works among controllers and directives?

I am sure I miss something, I can't believe the design was like this.

**updated: a solution is firing/listening all events on only rootScope, it works. but I still want to know angularjs is intent to design in this way.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check out this question:
[Can one controller call another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9293423/can-one-controller-call-another-in-angularjs)

Basically the best practice seems to be using a service instead of using the rootScope.