# How can i call a function that is in another controler (Angular js)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

in ControllerOne

```
$scope.displayReport = function( status ){

   statusCkeck( status ) ;
}
```

`statusCkeck() ;`  is in another controller -controllerTwo

How can i call this function from one controller to another

i tried `angular.element(document.getElementById('controllerTwo')).scope().statusCheck();`

But it throwing error.

Please suggest

Comment: But my case is different ,i just want to call another function ,no service calls

Comment: Please don't do this...

Comment: That is not angular way. Use a service if you want to share things between controllers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use a service instead to avoid muddying up the controllers with code that calls functions in other controllers. If you're sharing functions, just define them in a service and inject that service where needed.

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .factory('myService', function() {
    return {
      sharedFunction: function (foo, bar) {
        return foo + bar;
      }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get scope:

```
angular.element(document.getElementById('yourControllerElementID')).scope().get()
```

But *yourControllerElementID* should be **ElementID** not ControlerName!

For example:

```
<div id="elemID" ng-controller="YourController"></div>
```

So **elemId** is id of element with YourController.

Comment: Here i confused ,what is Element ID in the controller

Comment: See edit. Just take Id of element where you using your controller.

Comment: This should work but it's a terrible idea.  Tightly coupling your controllers like that leads to spaghetti code.

Comment: Yes this is not good solution. Maybe he can move method to service and use it globally :)