# How can I call a function that is defined in a different controller?

Tags: angularjs

One of the nice things about jQuery is that I can write a function and access it from anywhere within my application. AngularJS appears to be different and it is kind of frustrating. For example, I have the following code on my site:

```
<div id="myCtrl" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div ng-click="doSomething()">click here</div>
</div>
```

The problem is that `doSomething()` is defined in a different controller and therefore it doesn't work. This is a common problem that I have run in to and this aspect of AngularJS makes my app more complex than just using pure jQuery to define my functions. How can I call `doSomething()` from within any controller without having to create a service/factory, etc.? It just seems like that makes everything unnecessarily complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: you want a service/factory/...

Generally, when you find yourself wanting to call a controller function from a different controller that's a sign you should create a service.  You'll really end up with cleaner code that way. Using a service will make it clear to anyone reading your code that that service is needed by whatever controllers it's handed off to.

Having said that, check out: [Can one controller call another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9293423/can-one-controller-call-another-in-angularjs)   (in particular you may like: http://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-sharing-data-between-controllers)

Answer (score 0):

There is a reason why controllers can't access each other that way. It's just a kind of separation. The same reason why you don't declare all variables global in other languages.

If you want to do that, you should then have 1 big controller for your whole application, declaring it that way :

```
<body ng-controller="myCtrl">

</body>
```

But, I think it's a bad idea, and that you should learn services, factories,...