# Share data between two controllers in angularjs using restangular

Tags: json, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller, restangular

I am fairly new to angularjs, so please bear with me.

I have two controllers, one of which has a Restangular call to load a certain json object. How do I access this same json object in another controller without making another Restangular call?

I already tried making a `factory` that shares the object, but this is far from working.

```
app.factory('Data', function() {
    return []
}

app.controller("FirstCtrl", function ($scope, AudioRestangular, Data) {
    $scope.audios_full = Data
    // load data into $scope.audios_full using restangular
}

app.controller("SecondCtrl", function ($scope, AudioRestangular, Data) {
    /*
     * $scope.second_ctrl_audios = ?
     * get data from FirstCtrl's audios_full
     * and store it in this $scope.second_ctrl_audios
    */
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can one controller call another in AngularJS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9293423/can-one-controller-call-another-in-angularjs)

Comment: Show the code that is used to fill the data?

Answer (score 1):

You can go down the custom service / factory route, to effectively create your own caching layer as you suggest, or you can enable caching in Restangular. From https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#can-i-cache-requests

```
RestangularProvider.setDefaultHttpFields({cache: true});
```

You can probably put this in the "run" call of the app, like so:

```
app.run(function(RestangularProvider) {
  RestangularProvider.setDefaultHttpFields({cache: true});
});
```

Comment: Not run() function but I think config() function of the app.