# How to access the value of one controller from another controller in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller

I have two controller in an angularApp with following codes

**Controller:Devicectr**

```
function Devicectr($scope, $http) {
    $scope.Devices = [{ Id: 1, Devicename: "MasterDeviceA" },
     { Id: 1, Devicename: "MasterDeviceB" },
     { Id: 1, Devicename: "MasterDeviceC" }];
    $scope.ActiveDevice = $scope.Devices[0] // 
};
```

**Controller:PreviewCtr**

```
function Devicectr($scope, $http) {
 $scope.ViewDevice=null;  // Here i want to read the  $scope.ActiveDevice from **Devicectr** Controller

};
```

I want read the $scope.ActiveDevice value of **Devicectr** controller from **PreviewCtr** controller. How i can do it

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can one controller call another in AngularJS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9293423/can-one-controller-call-another-in-angularjs)

Answer (score 1):

Usually you use services when you want to share data between controllers.

Like:

```
yourModule.factory('yourService', function() {
    var sharedData = ...

    var getData = function() {
        return sharedData;
    }

    return {
        getData : getData
    }
}
```

and you then use this in both your controllers:

```
function Devicectr($scope, $http, yourService) {...}

function Previewctr($scope, $http, yourService) {...}
```

You could also nest the controllers to include the same scope, but I would say that  is a worse idea.

Comment: I attempted this approach but the problem i caught that,while page loading i got 0 value in previewCtr .even the device controller setup the value into the shared service . i found that the previCtr initializing before deviceCtr. i changed the order of the javascript reference but its not working. But i really confused that , i am using masterpages( ASP.NET)  the DeviceController executing in master page and PreviewController in Child page will it cause any issues in the order of execution of javscript

Comment: Do I understand correctly if you're not getting an updated value in Previewctrl when you change the value in Devicectrl?

Comment: Pingul, i can read the value by any control events like clicks and changes. My cause is different the execution of my page is ( proposed) given below .1) Devices controller load devices and set a shared data in sharedservice. then the previewController read this data from sharedservice whenever required

Comment: Yes that should work, although you will have to notify Previewctr every time a change has been made to refetch the data from the service.

Comment: Yes! i changed it its work but the problem is ,The first time when page loaded, it will not work there after i can read the value which changed by the Devicectr

Comment: This like i setup the Shared service in my app, will it cause any problem when injecting ( Check the new keyword, will it inject different instance)  TeslaApp.factory("SharedDataService", function() { return new SharedDataService(); });

Comment: And my shared service like   :: function SharedDataService() {

    var activeDeviceId = 0;

    this. getDeviceId = function() {
        return activeDeviceId;
    };
    this. setDeviceId = function(deviceId) {
        activeDeviceId = deviceId;
        
    };

    
}

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding your problem – please format your code if I'm supposed to read it. Although if you combine my answer with Chandermani's below, I think you should have everything you need.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `DeviceService` which keeps track of the currently selected device. It should expose  `setActive(device)` and `getActive()` method.

In your `PreviewCtr` inject the service to determine the active device. You need to watch for the Device assignment or `change`

If you assign the service to the scope like

`$scope.deviceService=deviceService;` you can do something like

```
$scope.$watch(function(){ return $scope.deviceService.getActive();},function(newValue,oldValue) {
  //This gets called when the device change
});
```

You and also use scope `$broadcast` method (using $rootScope) in the service to raise an event when the Device changes in `setDevice(device)` function. You can catch that event any where using `$scope.$on` handler. See documentation [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope).