# Call another controller from inside ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am new to angular and I am trying to call a function from another Controller. I do not want to define an addIssue function in ItemsController which calls IssuesController.addIssue or share a service, but directly reference the IssuesController. Is there any way to do that?

Here is my sample code:

```
<div ng-controller="ItemsController">
    <ul ng-repeat="item in items">
        <li><a href ng-click="addIssue(item)">{{item.name}}</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div ng-controller="IssuesController">
    <ul ng-repeat="issue in issues">
        <li>{{issue.name}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<script>
    angular.module('app').controller("IssuesController", function () {
        $scope.issues = [];
        $scope.addIssue = function (item) {
            // Add Issue
        }
    });
</script>
```

### UPDATE:

What if I have a third base controller to help them share $scope, how will that work?

```
<div ng-controller="OrdersController">
    <div ng-controller="ItemsController">
        <ul ng-repeat="item in items">
            <li><a href ng-click="addIssue(item)">{{item.name}}</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div ng-controller="IssuesController">
        <ul ng-repeat="issue in issues">
            <li>{{issue.name}}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, you want to call a controller from another controller? See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9293423/can-one-controller-call-another-in-angularjs

Answer (score 1):

As **EliteOctagon** mentioned, there are other and probably more "best practice" ways to achieve your goal but you can always do this the "dirty" way, you can use [$rootScope](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope) in your **ItemsController** to call the `addIssue(item)` function on **IssuesController**, and since all other scopes are descendant scopes of the **$rootScope** you can use it in any controller.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/choroshin/5YDJW/2/

Comment: I like this solution, even if it is 'dirty'

Comment: I know this is a bit old but you may want to look at doing a `$rootScope.$emit('addIssueEvent', item);` in the item controller and in the issue controller `$rootScope.$on('addIssueEvent', function(item) {/*do stuff*/});`

This way you will maintain uncoupled controllers

Answer (score 0):

There is, but it's such a terrible idea that you should think about it thoroughly. A much better solution  would be to put that functionality into a parent controller. Obviously you have functionality that is much broader in scope (pun intended) then just that div with the `IssuesController`.

Provided your code is a realistic sample, then `addIssue()` is not even used there. So it wouldn't even make sense to put it there.

One way to directly access `addIssue` is:

```
angular.element(/*select your div*/).scope().addIssue(item);
```

How you select your div depends. If i has an `id` you can use that. If you use jQuery then you can use `[ng-controller= ItemsController]`.

Comment: I saw that in another answer, but I agree it is a terrible idea.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you nest the controllers? You can read the Scope Inheritance Example at http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller

```
<div ng-controller="ItemsController">
    <ul ng-repeat="item in items">
        <li><a href ng-click="addIssue(item)">{{item.name}}</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div ng-controller="IssuesController"> <!-- nested and will inherit scope -->
        <ul ng-repeat="issue in issues">
            <li>{{issue.name}}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

so if you have a function in ItemsController

```
 $scope.addIssue = function() {do something}
```

then the IssuesController will inherit the $scope and you'll be able to use that function.

Comment: I did not want to nest them, because they are not that much related.