# How to update list after submitting form in Angular with a service?

Tags: javascript, forms, angularjs, frontend

I'm new to Angular and I'm trying to setup a basic "submit comment" & "show list of comments" page. I would like to have the list of comments be updated after submitting a comment. Currently I can submit, but must manually refresh the page to see it.

Controllers:

```
app.controller('FormController', function($scope, CommentService) {
    $scope.comment = {}; //will be populated by basic form
    $scope.submit = function() {
        return CommentService.post($scope.comment).then(function(){
            $scope.comment = ""; //blanks out form on POST
        });
    }
});

app.controller('CommentsController' function($scope, CommentService) {
    CommentService.list().then(function(comments){
        $scope.comments = comments.data;
    });
});
```

Service:

```
app.service('CommentService', function($http) {
    this.post = function(comment) {
        return $http.post('/api/v1/comments/', comment);
    };

    this.list = function() {
        return $http.get('/api/v1/comments/').
            success(function(data) {
                return data;
            });
    };

    //How do I connect the two controllers?
});
```

The HTML form/list is super generic, I just use "ng-repeat" to display comments. Am I on the right track here? Is there something simple I can do so when a comment is submitted via form, the list of comments will be updated?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9293423/can-one-controller-call-another-in-angularjs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along these lines would probably do it, just edit the semantics to match your program.

In your controller:

```
var getList = function() {
    $scope.comments = CommentService.list();
};

CommentService.registerObserverCallback(getList);
```

And in your service:

```
var observerCallbacks = [];

// register the observer's callback in our callback list.
this.registerObserverCallback = function(callback){
  observerCallbacks.push(callback);
};

// function to notify our observers and call the callback they registered with
var notifyObservers = function(){
  angular.forEach(observerCallbacks, function(callback){
   callback();
 });
};

this.post = function(comment) {

    return $http.post('/api/v1/comments/', comment).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        notifyObservers();
    })
 };
```

So basically your controller tells your service, "hey, I'm observing you.. If you do anything, call this call back function", and passes it `getList`. The service registers the observer, and calls the callback after the `post()` returns successful.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to get this to work. I looked at your other link and it seems like the "cleanest" way to use $rootScope to broadcast (but perhaps dangerous)? Passing callbacks around seems weird.

Comment: Glad it worked! I've found that the observer method is usually the preferred way, but that's definitely an option to consider. Good hunting!