# AngularJS to call a function in another controller from a link in ajax success function

Tags: angularjs

Angular JS - I need to call a function in another controller from an link, which has appended through ajax success function in one controller.

I have the following code in ajax success section in one controller,

```
     var acc_summ = '<a href="javascript:;" ng-click="test();" class="pull-right">Refresh</a>';
angular.element(acc_summ).appendTo('#itemsummeries');
```

I want to call test() function in another controller.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to provide more information and maybe show some HTML. Will the scope where this element is appended contain the test function?

Answer (score 0):

Emit an event in your current controller, and listen to that event in the second one (the one containing the `test` function). When the event is caught, call the function.

Also, remember that in general is bad practice to manipulate DOM in controllers, it should be done in directives.

Look for `$emit`, `$broadcast` and `$on`in the [$scope docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope)

And see also [Can one controller call another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9293423/can-one-controller-call-another-in-angularjs?rq=1)