# Use Angular ngClick to call function assigned to a different controller

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have two controllers, one controller being for a form, which is called when the form's button is clicked, and one controller being for a div, which is interpollated using scope and {{}}. The problem is that I need to pass the data collected after the form is submitted to the other controller. How can I call that second controller's function within the first controller's function:

```
//FIRST CONTROLLER, CALLED BY CLICKING BUTTON
app.controller('FormController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.IdSubmitted = function () {
        $scope.datatokens = json_datatokens;
        //WHERE I NEED TO CALL THE SECOND CONTROLLER, AND PASS IT "json_datatokens"
    }
});

//SECOND CONTROLLER
app.controller('#10Controller', function ($scope) { 

    $scope.datatokens = json_datatokens;    
});
```

HTML:

```
#FORM
<div ng-controller="FormController">
    <form class="search-wrapper" onsubmit='load_button();fetch_data();return false;'>
        <input type="text">
        <button type="submit" class="button " ng-click="IdSubmitted()">Submit Info</button>
    </form>

#DIV
        <div ng-controller='#10Controller' ng-init="init()">
            <p>Your payment is {{datatokens["DB.PMT"]}}</p>
        </div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9293423/can-one-controller-call-another-in-angularjs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the options suggested by sJhonny, you could use broadcasting with something like the following.

```
app.controller('FormController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.IdSubmitted = function () {
        $scope.$emit('formSubmission', json_datatokens);
    }
});

app.controller('#10Controller', function ($scope) { 
    $scope.$on('formSubmission', function(event, data) {
        $scope.datatokens = data;
    });  
});
```

Comment: I guess in this case I would replace the first $scope.datatokens (on the third line) with json_datatokens?

Comment: Yes. If it's declared and ready to use you can pass it to the $scope.$emit, however I couldn't see where you gave json_datatokens a value.

Comment: Oh right, that is collected through a GET request - I wasn't sure if it was relevant

Comment: Ok great. I've updated my answer to use json_datatokens instead. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

there are a couple of options-

1. use a shared object (I prefer a factory; you could go with a service as well) which both controllers reference. have the 1st controller set the data in that shared object, and the second one can read it.
   for example-

   ```
   app.factory('sharedStuffFactory', function() {
     return {
        sharedData: null; //that will be filled be one of the controllers
     }
   });
   ```

`app.controller('FormController', function ($scope, sharedStuffFactory) {
        $scope.IdSubmitted = function () {
            $scope.datatokens = json_datatokens;
            sharedStuffFactory.sharedData = json_datatokens;
        }
    });
    app.controller('#10Controller', function ($scope, sharedStuffFactory) { 
            $scope.datatokens = sharedStuffFactory.sharedData;

    });`

1. if you change your html structure a little to put the second div inside the first one, you could simply share a scope between them.