# How to call controller function from scope function and vice-versa in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am trying to call a controller function from `$scope` function. I am new bee in angular So I want all the ways I can call controller functions from `$scope` functions. Below is an example.

```
 app.directive('regionList' , function() {
    return {
        restrict : 'E' , 
        templateUrl: 'regions-panel.html',
        controller: ['$scope', '$filter', function($scope, $filter) {
          $scope.regions = regions_json;
            this.test = function() {
                console.log("Contoller function");
            };

          $scope.editRegionData = function() { 
               console.log("Scope Variable function");
               // How to call test function from here and also vice versa of that
          }
        }],
        controllerAs: "regionsCtrl"
    };

}) ; // End of Directive
```

Please also give an example to call a function from one module to a function in another module.

Comment: Your last part is not clear: what sort of function are you trying to call in a module? Is it a function available as a property on a service, or what?

Comment: See difference between this and $scope here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11605917/this-vs-scope-in-angularjs-controllers . As for the cross modules/controllers communication using service is the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9293423/can-one-controller-call-another

Comment: okay..  In my last part I want to call a function which is in separate module and my current module is dependent on that module. therefore how to call that function inside controller of that parent module.

Comment: @ShivekParmar That is only slightly more helpful. Functions are _everywhere_ in Javascript and AngularJS, what particular function are you trying to call? It would probably help to be specific.

Comment: @ShivekParmar can you provide more concrete example code, what you want to call from where?

Comment: okay leave my last part just answer the first part of question