# how to create reusable component in angularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I have two controllers at the moment, one is a form where a user inputs a value and the other is a graph that renders based on an api search. I would need to refresh or re run the second controller based on the input from the first. I am almost certain this is bad design on my part but have not found the ideal way to do it.

**HTML code:**

```
<html>
<body>


<!-- this is the graph generator-->
<div ng-controller="GraphAppCtrl"></div>

<!-- this is th form submittal section-->
<div ng-controller="FormCtrl" id="FormCtrl">

 <form novalidate class="simple-form">
    Name: <input type="text" ng-model="tech"/><br />

    <button ng-click="submit(tech)">Submit</button>
  </form>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Angular Code:**

```
var app = angular.module('testApp', []);


app.controller('FormCtrl', function ($scope) {

    $scope.submit = function(tech){

   // Need to be able to call the function that generates graph and pass it the tech value

     }
}

app.controller('GraphAppCtrl', function ($scope) {

//here I do a bunch of stuff to generate graph, like http request from third party api etc.


  }
```

What is happening now since I have a reference to the graph controller in the my index.html page it renders the first time based on default parameters, but I would need it to render based on the submit.

I have looked Directives and experimented with the answer in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9407953/1754020)  but it seems as Directives more of a solution to pass data between controllers rather than what I am trying to do.

Comment: check out services/factories https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create an Angular Service

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services