# Accessing data of a controller in another controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller

I am working on a application which uses angularjs. In this i have a login page and  home page.
Whole page is divided into two parts **header** and **container** each with **headerCtrl** and **loginCtrl** respectively.
header is same for both parts and only rest part changes after login.

This is loginCtrl.

```
    angular.module('app').controller('LoginCtrl', ['$scope', 'LoginService',
    function($scope, LoginService) {
        $scope.title = "Login";

        $scope.login = function() {
            var user = {
                username: $scope.username,
                password: $scope.password
            };
            LoginService(user);
        };

    }
]);
```

This is loginService.

```
angular.module('app')
.factory('LoginService', function($http, $location, $rootScope) {
    return function(user) {
        $http.post('/login',{
                username: user.username,
                password: user.password
            }).then(function(response) {
            if (response.data.success) {
                console.log(response.data);
                $rootScope.user = response.data.user;
                $location.url('/');
            } else {
                console.log(response.data.errorMessage);
                $location.url('/');
            }
        });
    };
});
```

This is header.html

```
<div ng-controller="headerCtrl" class="container-fulid">
    <div class="row custom-row1">
        <div><span class="title_top pull-right">{{ user }}</span></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**How can we write headerCtrl and what changes are required in login controller and service so that i can access the user details(username) in header.html file.**

Comment: if header controller present inside login controller, u can directly access

Comment: how can you provide more details. is it possible to define a controller inside another controller.

Comment: Yes!! You can use one controller inside another controller.

Comment: how ? can you provide some link or samplre related to it.

Comment: Yes!! wait a moments

Comment: It might help you!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9293423/can-one-controller-call-another http://plnkr.co/edit/poeq460VmQER8Gl9w8Oz?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

It might help you!!

Your HTML code-sample

```
<div ng-controller="loginCtrl" class="container-fulid">
    <div class="row custom-row1">
        <div><span class="title_top pull-right">{{ title }}</span></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Your AngularJs code-sample

```
var baseURL = "http://localhost:56110/";
var app = angular.module('loginApp', []);

app.service('loginService', function ($http) {
    this.login = function (user) {
        return $http.post('/login', user)
          .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {              
           })
           .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {               
           });
          }
        });
    };
});

app.controller('loginCtrl', function ($scope, loginService) {

    $scope.title = "Login";
    $scope.uid = 123;
    $scope.pwd = 123;

    $scope.login = function () {
        var pwd = {
            username: $scope.uid,
            password: $scope.pwd
        };

        loginService.login(pwd).then(function (response) {               
            if (response.data.success) {
                console.log(response.data);
                $rootScope.user = response.data.user;
                $location.url('/');
            }
            else {
                console.log(response.data.errorMessage);
                $location.url('/');
            }
        });
    };
});
```

Comment: seems like Login comes in  in title of html. but i want that uid comes at that place.

Comment: You can put the uid at the place of title.

Answer (score 0):

U can use a broadcast  on the $rootscope from login controller when ur lgon service completes and listen to the use event in headercontroller.the event argument you can pass as the user details.