# Emitting data across controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I was trying to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9407953/830469) exampled provided by the Angular creator Vojta. However, I can't seem to get the emit to work properly. 
Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nopctoday/fp2y3jur/2/

```
<div ng-module="myapp">
    <div ng-controller="ControllerZero">
        <button ng-click="pass_data()">BROADCAST</button>
    </div>

    <div ng-controller="ControllerOne">
        {{data}}
    </div>
</div>
```

and the simple js

```
var myModule = angular.module('myapp', []);

app.controller('ControllerZero',['$scope',function($scope){
    $scope.pass_data = function() {
        $scope.$emit('broadcasting', 'it succeeded!');
    };
}]);

app.controller('ControllerOne',['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.data = "";
    $scope.$on('broadcasting', function(event, data) {
        $scope.data = data;
    });
}]);
```

Comment: I thought [Misko](http://misko.hevery.com/about/) created Angular.

Comment: my bad. You are right. I am still interested in why my implementation didn't not though.

Comment: Try [$rootScope](http://jsfiddle.net/amullins/fr9kj3cm/2/). Really, you're better off using a custom service.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14502006/working-with-scope-emit-and-on

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$emit` bubbles the event upwards the scope hierarchy, including the current scope.

`$broadcast` sends the event downwards the scope hierarchy, including the current scope.

In your case, the scope of `ControllerZero` and the scope of `ControllerOne` are siblings, so `$scope.$emit` doesn't reach the sibling scope.

Depending on the variety of listeners that you intend to reach, you could either do:

**#1**

```
$scope.$root.$emit("eventName", ...); // or $rootScope
```

that will reach listeners of `$rootScope`:

```
$rootScope.$on("eventName", ...)
```

or, **#2**, you could broadcast from the root:

```
$scope.$root.$broadcast("eventName", ...)
```

that will reach all listeners

```
$scope.$on("eventName", ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have some typos in your code. Also the 2 controllers so not share the same scope. So if you want to broadcast events between them you need to use the root scope:

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);

app.controller('ControllerZero', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.pass_data = function() {
        $scope.$emit('broadcasting', 'it succeeded!');
    };
}]);

app.controller('ControllerOne', ['$scope', '$rootScope', function($scope, $rootScope) {
    $scope.data = null;
    $rootScope.$on('broadcasting', function(data, args) {
        $scope.data = args;
    });
}]);
```

and here's a sample fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3epo5ckz/1/

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the issue is that `$emit` sends events up the scope chain. Its companion, `$broadcast`, sends things down the scope chain. The example you provided seems like it would only work in some cases. The way I've accomplished this in the past is like this:

*ctrlOne.js*

```
angular.module('app').controller(function($rootScope) {
  $rootScope.$broadcast('broadcasting', 'message');
});
```

*ctrlTwo.js*

```
angular.module('app').controller(function($scope) {
  $scope.$on('broadcasting', function(msg) {
    // should output 'message'
    console.log(msg);
  });
});
```

You could also alias this process with some service like this:

*messenger.service.js*

```
angular.module('app').factory(function($rootScope) {
  return {
    send: $rootScope.$broadcast,
    on: $rootScope.$on
  };
}
```

You can read Angular's documentation on [`$on`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$on), [`$emit`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$emit), and [`$broadcast`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$broadcast).

Answer (score 0):

If you have a large application and don't want to pollute it with messages from the root scope you can also use your parent to broadcast. That way only your sibling and child controllers will receive the event.

```
$scope.$parent.$broadcast("eventName", ...);
```