# Is it possible to inject a controller from another module into a controller?

Tags: angularjs

I have to call a method from `controllerA` in `module A` in `controllerB` in `module B`.
I don't want to use `$broadcast` or `$emit`. Nor do I want to use `$inject`.

Please help with another way to achieve this.

Comment: Why you don't want to use $emit, $inject or service?

Comment: Use a `service`. Its easier and cleaner.

Comment: the app i am working on is huge. so usage of $rootscope methods is limited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29927130/4653126) link answers your question.