# Reusing of functions which is defined between controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, inheritance

i would like to reuse the code defined between the controllers

```
.controller('GenericController', ['$scope', '$controller', '$rootScope', '$dialogs', '$state', '$http', '$modal', '$q', '$timeout', 'projectFactory', 'projectPromise', 'phaseFactory', 'buFactory', 'stakeholderGroupFactory', 'ldapFactory', 'genericFactory', 'User',

    function ($scope, $controller, $rootScope, $dialogs, $state, $http, $modal, $q, $timeout, projectFactory, projectPromise, phaseFactory, buFactory, stakeholderGroupFactory, ldapFactory, genericFactory, User) {

      $scope.testing = function() {
        console.log("Hello");
      };
}]);
```

Comment: You can use a service to achieve this.

Comment: i am using a service. but i would like to intitiate the inheritace of code in side controllers

Comment: [Use as little code as possible that still produces the same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: If you are using a service, then post the code for the same and explain properly where you are facing the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used the `$controller` for the importing this fixed my issue

Answer (score 3):

You can use the factory and create the object for the function to reuse it.

```
app.factory("sample",function(){
    return function() {
        console.log("Hello");
      };
})
```

else collating multiple common functions

```
app.factory("commonFunctions",function(){

    commonFunction1(){
       console.log("common func1")
    } 

    commonFunction2(){
       console.log("common func2")
    } 

   return {
         commonFunction1: commonFunction1,
         commonFunction1: commonFunction2
   };
})
```

Comment: Will factory act a a mirror for the controller communication

Comment: If you want to communicate between the controllers you can use service or localstorage or broadcast or cache, those will store the date and you can use it in other controllers. To reuse the functions you can create a factory, you can define what to be returned in factory.