# AngularJS factory with $http and multiple controllers

Tags: angularjs

I want multiple controllers to be able to update a single view attached to one controller using a factory with $http.

My list view:

```
<div class="list" ng-repeat="image in images" ng-controller="controller1">
   <div lass="item"><img src="{{image.url}}" /></div>
</div>
```

Service:

```
.factory("imageService", function($http) {
  return {
    getImages: function() {
      return $http({
        method: "get",
        url: "http://example.com/images",
        params: { user: window.localStorage['user_id'] }
      })
    }
  }
});
```

Controller 1:

```
.controller('controller1', function($scope, imageService) {
   window.localStorage['user_id'] = '101';
   var handleSuccess = function(data, status) {
       $scope.images = data;
   };
   imageService.getImages().success(handleSuccess);
})
```

This all works. When the app is loaded, the list immediately is populated with a list of images for user '101'.

In another controller, I want to be able to switch users and automatically re-poupulate the image list in the view from controller 1 with new images.

Controller 2:

```
.controller('controller2', function($scope, imageService) {
   window.localStorage['user_id'] = '202';
   imageService.getImages();
})
```

So controller 2 will run getImages() and I can see the $http request working via chrome dev tools / XHR.  And I know why the list view attached to controller1 is not populating, but I dont know how to make it populate. I have tried moving the success callback into the service and setting a 'images' property on the service and a $scope.images in controller1, but no luck there.

How can I force the new list of images into the view attached to controller 1?

Comment: You could emit an event from the rootScope to the controller and the listener for the emit handles loading the images from the imageService.

Comment: @tafoo85  Is using $rootScope definitely required to get the image list updated?

Comment: Nah, it was off the top of my head quick two second solution.  That other guy's idea is better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should just manage a list into your service that you will bind to your `controller1` :

```
.factory("imageService", function($http) {
    var service = {};
    service.images = {};
    service.images.list = [];
    service.getImages = function(userId) {
      window.localStorage['user_id'] = userId;
      return $http({
        method: "get",
        url: "http://example.com/images",
        params: { user: userId }
      }).success(function(data){
          service.images.list = data
      });
    }

  //at the initialization of the service, you launch the getImages once with the localStorage value.
  service.getImages(window.localStorage['user_id']);

  return service;
});
```

Then you can bind it like this in your controllers :

```
.controller('controller1', function($scope, imageService) {
   $scope.images = imageService.images;
   //then access it in the view with images.list
   imageService.getImages(101);
})

.controller('controller2', function($scope, imageService) {
   $scope.images = imageService.images;
   //then access it in the view with images.list
   imageService.getImages(202);
})
```

Note that using a sub object (`images.list` instead of `images`) is important.

If you want some more precise informations about why this sub object is needed you can read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30510369/2516560) on this subject

Hope it helped.

Comment: So in the view,  ng-repeat="image in images.list".      This seems to work well. Let me test.

Comment: @lilbiscuit How is the integration doing ? Feel free to ask if you need some help. That's exactly how the ng-repeat will look like.

Comment: @lilbiscuit Btw, why don't you use a var with your get function instead of using the local storage ?

Comment: @Okazzari - I use localStorage to preserve the user selection (this is a mobile hybrid app).

Comment: @lilbiscuit i'm not sure i understood your question but you can manage the user_id local storage into the service. I'll update the answer to show how.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just use one controller. At some time point, say, a user clicks some button, reload the image lists and re-render the view to show the list.

For example, make the factory like:

```
.factory("imageService", function($http) {
  return {
    getImages: function(userId) {
      return $http({
        method: "get",
        url: "http://example.com/images",
        params: { user: userId }
      });
    }
  };
});
```

And in the controller:

```
.controller('imageController', function($scope, imageService) {

   function refreshImages (userId) {
     imageService.getImages(userId).success(function(data) {
       $scope.$apply(function () {
         $scope.images = data;
       });
     });
   }

   refreshImages('101');
   $scope.loadImages = function (userId) {
     refreshImages(userId);
   };
});
```

Comment: I need to be able to update the list from within multiple controllers.

Comment: Well, if the two controllers shares the same scope, you need to call `$scope.$apply` after getting new list of images.

Comment: I still cannot imagine your scenario. Controllers should not share such kind of logic. You either extract to service/factory or directive.

Comment: The scenario is that each view in my app has its own controller. One view / controller displays the list of images. The other view/controller displays a list of users. Select a user in controller2 view, and see the resulting images for the selected user controller1 view.