# Using service to broadcast message in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I need to call a function from another controller in Angular JS. Another question on Stack Overflow suggests to use a service instead:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11847277/1910735

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0z7ux66c/

So I created a service, and two controllers:

```
    var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

    app.factory('trackingService', function ($rootScope) {

        var trackingInstance = {};

        trackingInstance.assetInformationModel = null;

        trackingInstance.RefreshDashboard = function () {
            $rootScope.$broadcast('Refresh');
        };

        return trackingInstance;
    });

    app.controller('assetInformationController', function ($scope,  trackingService) {
        $scope.UpdateDashboard = function () {
            console.log('UpdateDashboard()')
            trackingService.RefreshDashboard();
        };

        $scope.$on('Refresh', function () {

// THIS gets called
            console.log('Refresh');
        });


    });

    app.controller('liveTrackingController', function ($scope,  trackingService){
        $scope.$on('Refresh', function () {

// THIS doesn't
            console.log('Refresh in liveTrackingController');
        });


    });
```

From the code, it should display the following three lines in Console:

```
UpdateDashboard()
Refresh
Refresh in liveTrackingController
```

But it is not calling the `Reresh` Event from `liveTrackingController` - It is only displaying:

```
UpdateDashboard()
Refresh
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your jsfiddle, the liveTrackingController is not being used anywhere.

Add something like this into your html to get the desired log output.

```
<div ng-controller="liveTrackingController"></div>
```