# Call a controller from another controller in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have got a problem with calling a controller(not just a function) from another controller. My HTML looks like:

```
<div ng-app="MyApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div id="msg"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the script:

```
var module = angular.module('MyApp', []);

module.controller('MyCtrl', [function() {
    angular.element(document).ready(function () {
        test();
    });
}]);

module.controller('test', [function() {
    document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = 'Hello';
}]);
```

Please see the jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/y35emhny/

Is there any way how I can achieve it?

Comment: Well, to start with you haven't included your test controller in your dom, how do you expect it to be loaded? Secondly, controllers don't exchange values directly, you use a service for that. There's tons of examples online, and here on SO as well, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9293423/can-one-controller-call-another?rq=1 for instance

Comment: Please refer to : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9293423/can-one-controller-call-another