# How to call second controller when first controller has been loaded and rendered in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I have a requirement to call another controller after the first one is loaded and rendered. Means I want to call controllers one-by-one, when one controller is successfully loaded and rendered then another controller is initiated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9293423/can-one-controller-call-another

Comment: @FurkanBaşaran but how to know my first controller has been loaded and rendered?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use $broadcast, using this you can notify the other controller when something changes on your first controller.

Angular provides $broadcast, $on and $emit for this.

[answered here](https://scotch.io/tutorials/angular-routing-using-ui-router)

And if above is not fits your requirement you should use AngularJS stateprovider (ui-router and define states and bound your controller.

First call state1 which has controller1, if everything goes fine within that controller call state2 which has controller2

$state.go("state2");

```
var routerApp = angular.module('module-name', ['ui.router']);

routerApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/state1');

    $stateProvider        

        .state('state1', {
            url: '/state1',
            templateUrl: 'state1.html',
        controller : 'controller1'
        })


        .state('state2', {
            url: '/state2',
            templateUrl: 'state2.html',
        controller : 'controller2'
        })

});
```

Index.html

```
<div ui-view></div>
```

[ui-router example here](https://scotch.io/tutorials/angular-routing-using-ui-router)

Controller like

```
routerApp.controller("controller1", ['$state', function($state){
//after 

$state.go("state2");

}]);
```