# How do I pass angular array list to controller

Tags: angularjs

I added list of item value store in array, how do I pass angular array list to controller.

$scope.AddRecord = [];

```
$scope.AddUpdateItem = function (item_id, item_discription, item_quantity, item_unit, item_rate, item_discount) {

    var getItemAction = $scope.Action;

    if (getItemAction == "Update") {

        $scope.AddRecord[key].budget_item_id = item_id;
        $scope.AddRecord[key].budget_item_discription = item_discription;
        $scope.AddRecord[key].budget_item_quantity = item_quantity;
        $scope.AddRecord[key].budget_item_unit = item_unit;
        $scope.AddRecord[key].budget_item_rate = item_rate;
        $scope.AddRecord[key].budget_item_discount = item_discount; 

        $scope.divItem = false; 
        ClearFields();
    } else
    {  
        $scope.AddRecord.push({ 'budget_item_id': $scope.item_id, 'budget_item_discription': $scope.item_discription, 'budget_item_quantity': $scope.item_quantity, 'budget_item_unit': $scope.item_unit, 'budget_item_rate': $scope.item_rate, 'budget_item_discount': $scope.item_discount });
        ClearFields();
    }
    }
```

I added list of item value store in array  but i am not able pass list to controller,so please somebody help me how to pass angular array list to controller

Comment: do you want to pass it another controller or want to use within

Comment: thanks for replay  i want to pass my asp.net mvc controller because i need store value in database

Comment: please have a look .. are you looking for this.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9293423/can-one-controller-call-another/31469444#31469444

Comment: ok ,i seen  this link, but i don't understand how to post array list  values  on serverside

Comment: then you need to use $http service to post data to server.

Comment: this.AddItem = function (item) {
        var response = $http({
            method: "post",
            url: '/Budget/AddBudgetItem',
            data: JSON.stringify(item),
            dataType: "json"
        });  return response;   I make it services     but how to assign array list

Comment: In else condition where you are calling clearfields you can call service function and yourservice.AddItem(item) in controller

Comment: plase help me how to assgin array list to sevices

Comment: ok thank you i'll try

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understood you ,please have a look on it and let me know if you still face some issue

```
 $scope.AddUpdateItem = function (item_id, item_discription, item_quantity, item_unit, item_rate, item_discount) {

        var getItemAction = $scope.Action;

        if (getItemAction == "Update") {

            $scope.AddRecord[key].budget_item_id = item_id;
            $scope.AddRecord[key].budget_item_discription = item_discription;
            $scope.AddRecord[key].budget_item_quantity = item_quantity;
            $scope.AddRecord[key].budget_item_unit = item_unit;
            $scope.AddRecord[key].budget_item_rate = item_rate;
            $scope.AddRecord[key].budget_item_discount = item_discount; 

            $scope.divItem = false; 
            ClearFields();
        } else
        {  
            var item = { 'budget_item_id': $scope.item_id, 'budget_item_discription': $scope.item_discription, 'budget_item_quantity': $scope.item_quantity, 'budget_item_unit': $scope.item_unit, 'budget_item_rate': $scope.item_rate, 'budget_item_discount': $scope.item_discount }
            $scope.AddRecord.push(item);
            myService.addItem(item);//call service to send data to server
            ClearFields();
        }
        }
```

Service

```
myapp.service('myService',function($http){

    this.additem = function (item) { 
       var response = $http({ 
             method: "post", 
             url: '/Budget/AddBudgetItem', 
             data: JSON.stringify(item),
             dataType: "json" 
     }); 
     return response;
}

});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Shubhan ,for this help , My issue solved

Comment: Upvote and validate answer and keep helping others as well.. :)

Comment: while receiving in Spring Controller we have to use PostMapping along with RequestBody ?