# Best practice : calling $scoped function from a header controller into a view controller?

Tags: angularjs, service, controller

I'm using angular-ui router and I have a very simple todo app I'm making to learn more about angular 1.4. If I have my `<ui-view></ui-view>` tags for my home controller, what is the best way to have a click in the header (to add a task effect my home view + controller?)

(My header HTML just has some anchor buttons, like add task, refresh list)

Header controller :

```
angular.controller('headerController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

  $scope.addTask = function(){
    //add a task or show toggle task form or call to something below in home controller
  }

}]);
```

My home controller:

```
angular.controller('homeController', ['$scope', 'getTasks', function($scope, getTasks) {

  $scope.todos = getTasks.load;

}]);
```

Should a service be made for something so simple? Or is this a job for rootscope, I know that rootscope should be avoided though as it pollutes global namespace. Thank you

Comment: What are you doing in `getTasks.load;`?

Comment: Thats a service that calls $http to load from mongolab, then in my home view I used ng-repeat directive and interpolated the data. Basically its just a load function to get the data

Comment: So, it's correct...

Comment: What I'm saying if I wanted to access a function from the header controller to the home controller... Is that bad practice? Say that it's even just a helloworld() function and I wanted to call it from my header controller, is that even possible

Comment: I guess its either a service, or emitting on $scope http://stackoverflow.com/a/9407953/6492029