# Call a Controller angularjs in another Controller angularjs

Tags: angularjs, controller

Well my problem is I have 2 controllers... and I wanna know whether is possible call any function from them in order to do work them together... 
For instance:

**firstController.js**

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('FirstController', ['$scope', 'FirstService', function($scope, FirstService) {
    function verify(){
        //Some operations
    }
}]);
```

**secondController.js**

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('SecondController', ['$scope', 'SecondService', function($scope, SecondService) {
    function edit(iditem){
        //Some operations
        //I wanna call here verify() function
    }
}]);
```

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No, it's not. Especially since those functions are completely private to the controller. Use a service, or events, to make your controllers collaborate. Hard to say more without a concrete use-case.

Comment: Did you try this solution ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9293423/can-one-controller-call-another

Comment: Ok.. and How could get call 2 services in a controller by this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it with only one service and call service from both controllers. This is a basic example, you could add a constructor and pass it $scope for example it depends on what you want to accomplish.

```
'use strict';

/**
 * Service
 */

angular.module('myApp.someService', [])
        .factory("someService", function () {

           return {   
               verify: function() {},
               edit: function(iditem){
                   self.verify();
               }
});
```

Then your controllers would look like this:

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('FirstController', ['$scope', 'someService', function($scope, someService) {

   service.verify($scope);

}]);

angular.module('myApp').controller('SecondController', ['$scope', 'someService', function($scope, someService) {

    service.edit(iditem);

}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

### Using Prototypical Inheritance

If the controllers are nested:

```
<div ng-controller="FirstController">

    <div ng-controller="SecondController">

    </div>

</div>
```

If the FirstController publishes its functions on `$scope`, the nested controllers can invoke the functions by prototypical inheritance.

**Publish function on $scope:**

```
app.controller('FirstController', function($scope) {

    $scope.firstVerify = verify;

    function verify(){
        //Some operations
    }
});
```

**Invoke by $scope inheritance:**

```
app.controller('SecondController', function($scope) {
    function edit(iditem){
        //Some operations
        //I wanna call here verify() function
        $scope.firstVerify();
    }
});
```

This will only work if the second controller's scope is a child scope of the first controller's scope.

As you can see, there are many answers to the question. Which answer to use depends on the specific use case.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that through `$rootScope` controller

include $rootScope in FirstContoller, assign a function:

```
$rootScope.myFirstController_verify = verify;
```

And call it from second controller with `$rootScope` included:

```
$rootScope.myFirstController_verify();
```