# AngularJS $stateprovider

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angularjs, I am not able to understand the concept of $stateprovider
I want to create a header that has menu and logo and the body content should change when clicked on menu items accordingly, code is given below, please check and answer my query

HTML

`<div ui-view = "header"></div>
<div ui-view = "content"></div>`

JS

```
var App=angular.module('test', ["ui.router", "App.controllers", "ui.bootstrap"]);

App.config(function ($stateProvider){
    $stateProvider
        .state('test', {
          url: '',
          views: {
            'header': { templateUrl: '/templates/header.html'}

         }
      });
})
```

Thank You

Comment: This might help you.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9293423/can-one-controller-call-another

Comment: use ng-href to go to different state in case of stateProvider from any element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have taken two views, one for `header` and other for `content`,

```
<div ui-view = "header"></div>
<div ui-view = "content"></div>
```

The route also should have two different named routes.

```
views: {
            'header': { templateUrl: '/templates/header.html'},
            'content': { templateUrl: '/templates/content.html'}
         }
```

From this,

`<div ui-view = "header"></div>` opens `header.html` and `<div ui-view = "content"></div>` opens `content.html`

Here is the code,

```
var App=angular.module('test', ["ui.router", "App.controllers", "ui.bootstrap"]);

App.config(function ($stateProvider){
    $stateProvider
        .state('test', {
          url: '',
          views: {
            'header': { templateUrl: '/templates/header.html'},
            'content': { templateUrl: '/templates/content.html'}
         }
      });
})
```

In the HTML,

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills main-menu right">
   <li role="presentation"><a ui-sref="test" class="active">Home</a></li>
   <li role="presentation"><a href="#/bus_chart">Bus Chart</a></li>
   <li role="presentation"><a href="#/bookings">My Bookings</a></li>
   <li role="presentation"><a href="#/review">Reviews</a></li>
   <li role="presentation"><a href="#/contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

The first `li` click goes to our `test state` as given in routes.

[Here is the documentation for the same](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-views)

Comment: @Lakshmi, please check my answer.

Comment: my content view has to be changed whenever I click on nav-items in header, how that can be achieved?

Comment: <ul class="nav nav-pills main-menu right">
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#/" class="active">Home</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#/bus_chart">Bus Chart</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#/bookings">My Bookings</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#/review">Reviews</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#/contact">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>

Comment: `<li role="presentation"><a ui-sref="test" class="active">Home</a></li>`

Comment: the above line navigates to the given state(test)

Answer (score 0):

**In config File**

```
// State definitions
$stateProvider
  .state('test', {
    abstract: true,
    views: {
    'main@': {
        templateUrl: 'app/../../full-view.html'
      },
      'header@test': {
        templateUrl: '/templates/header.html' // correct path to the template
        //  controller: 'HeaderController as vm'   if needed
      },
      'footer@test': {
        templateUrl: '/templates/footer.html' // correct path to the template
        //  controller: 'FooterController as vm'   if needed
      }
    }
  });
```

**HTML**

in content-only.html

```
<div>
     <div ui-view = "content"></div>
</div>
```

in full-view.html

```
<div class="container">
  <div ui-view="header"></div>
  <div>
    <div ui-view="content"></div>
  </div>
  <div ui-view="footer"></div>
  </div>
```

**in index.html**

```
<body>
    <div ui-view="main"></div>
  </body>
```

in other modules(example)

```
views: {
        'content@test': {
          templateUrl: 'app/main/policies/policies.html'
        //  controller: 'PoliciesController as vm'   if needed
        }
      }
```

so that whatever you append to content@test will comes under ui-view="content"

**for routing** avoid using `href=""`, use `ui-sref=""` since you are using **ui-router**

example `ui-sref="app.home" or ui-sref="app.about"` rather than using`href="#/home"  or  href="#/about"`