# How to submit form from a different controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to submit multiple forms from different controllers but I'm not sure how. The reason for this is because I have a save button on multiple different tabs of my webpage. By clicking save I want to submit the form and then validate it. I want to submit my forms from main controller and I don't know how to refer to the forms.

This is my form

```
<form name="vm.driverForm" novalidate>
    <formly-form class="top20" model="vm.model" fields="vm.fields" options="vm.options" form="vm.driverForm"></formly-form>
</form>
```

and submit function in my main controller

```
vm.onSubmit = onSubmit;
function onSubmit() {
    $scope.vm.driverForm.$setSubmitted();  //THIS IS THE PART I'M TRYING TO FIGURE OUT
}
```

and the button in the main controller

```
<button type="button" ng-click="vm.onSubmit()" class="btn btn-primary submit-button top5">Save Driver</button>
```

I don't want to copy and paste my submit function and save button code into every single controller that uses the button.

Comment: do you mean this by vm? if it is the case then you should remove the $scope from your js file and vm from the html

Comment: vm.driverForm is not part of the same controller where the function lives. That's why I've been trying to use $scope.vm.driverForm

Comment: or how can I check if form on controller X is valid from controller Y?

Comment: @nour,  'vm' means view-model. You can use controllerAs property to alias $ctrl as anything, say vm. Now you could do vm.popertyname instead of $ctrl.propertyname.

Answer (score 1):

Use **Services**.

Say you created a service, **EventService**.

Whenever you want to submit the form from another controller, emit an event.

```
EventService.$emit("submit-event");
```

Add a listener to that event in your main controller, which will execute the onSubmit function.

```
EventService.$on("submit-event", vm.onSubmit);
```

Note 1:  Service class must extend the **EventEmitter** class

Note 2: Both the controller must use a common service to emit and listen the event.

[Can one controller call another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9293423/can-one-controller-call-another)