# Communication between AngularJS controllers

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript, angularjs-controlleras

I'm trying to trigger an action defined in one controller from second one. I've gone through [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9293423/can-one-controller-call-another), but I can't see what I am doing wrong. Here goes the code:

```
window.cartApp = angular.module 'cartApp', ['pascalprecht.translate', 'directives', 'cartServices',
    'angular-click-outside']

class CartCtrl
    constructor: (@$scope, @$http, @$timeout, @$filter, PriceOption, EnableMealsService, CookiesService) ->
        @$scope.cartItems = {'meals': [], 'submeals': []}
        @$scope.Math = window.Math;

        _scope = @$scope

        _http = @$http
        window.cartApp.config(window.translate)
        @$scope.$on('triggerGetQuote', () -> console.log('getting quote'))


class IndexCtrl
    constructor: (@$scope, @$rootScope, @$http, CookiesService) ->
        _scope = @$scope
        _rootScope = @$rootScope
        _http = @$http
        @$scope.getLocation = () ->
            console.log('Before broadcast of triggerGetQuote')
            _scope.$broadcast('triggerGetQuote')


CartCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$http', '$timeout', '$filter', 'PriceOption', 'EnableMealsService', 'CookiesService']
IndexCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$http', 'CookiesService']
window.cartApp.controller 'CartCtrl', CartCtrl
window.cartApp.controller 'IndexCtrl', IndexCtrl
```

So I'm expecting to get both events logged in my console, however, only the first one is triggered:

> Before broadcast of triggerGetQuote

Comment: try changing  `_scope.$broadcast` to `_rootScope.$broadcast`

Comment: @AlekseySolovey It helped. I'll be glad to accept it as an answer.