# Controller is not registering with angular js spa

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My spa showing below error...i hardly tried but am not getting solution...am new to angular...any help is appreciated...

> Err::[$controller:ctrlreg] The controller with the name 'Mcontroller'
>   is not registered.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html ng-app="Dapp">
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<script type="text/javascript" src="JS/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="JS/angular-route.js"></script>
<title>DAPP</title>
</head>
<body ng-controller="Mcontroller">
<div class="ng-view"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="controllers/Mcontroller.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="controllers/Controller.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="controllers/Logincontrol.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

**contrller.js**

```
var app=angular.module('Dapp',['ngRoute']);
app.config(function($routeProvider) {

     $routeProvider
      .when('/', {templateUrl : 'Pages/login.html',controller  : 'Mcontroller' })
      .when('/login', {templateUrl : 'Pages/login.html',controller  : 'Logincontrol' })     
});
```

**Mcontrol.js**

```
app.controller('Mcontroller',function($scope){

        alert("HELLO");

});
```

**Login.html**

```
hello Buddy......
```

Comment: Make sure your Mcontrol.js is properly linked or not, comment your routing code and simply leave alert.

Comment: You have to order the .js files. First your angular.module have to load. Seems your controller.js. then the rest.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can one AngularJS controller call another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9293423/can-one-angularjs-controller-call-another)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change the sequence to:

(Below sequence assumes that `angular.module('Dapp',[]);` is present in `Controller.js` file)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="controllers/Controller.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="controllers/Mcontroller.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="controllers/Logincontrol.js"></script>
```

Make sure, `angular.module('Dapp',[]);` is **included** in `<script> as the 1st`js` file in html page.

Comment: @Dhanunjaysharma Cheers ! ;) Upvote if u want to as well