# AngularJS invoke a controller function from another controller

Tags: angularjs, sorting, columnsorting

In my project I am having a paginated table in table.html(directive) and i have its corresponding controller (table.js).

Please see the code snippets from each file.

```
`======================== table.html ============================
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        Search: &emsp; &emsp;<input ng-model="searchText"  ng-change="searchChange(searchText)"/>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">

        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th class="text-center"><a href='#' ng-click="sortlist('product')">Product</a></th>
                    <th class="text-center">Service Name</th>
                    <th class="text-center">Distributor Name</th>
                    <th class="text-center">Type</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="data in paged_data">
                    <td class="text-center"><cc-customer-geo geo-code="sku.geoCode"></cc-customer-geo></td>
                    <td class="text-center">{{data.product}}</td>
                    <td class="text-center">{{data.ServiceName}}</td>
                    <td class="text-center">{{data.DistributorName}}</td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="text-center" ng-switch="data.type">
                            <span class="text-center" ng-switch-when="0">Trial</span>
                            <span class="text-center" ng-switch-when="1">Licensed</span>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <my-paged-data input-data="input_data_list" paged-data="paged_data"></my-paged-data>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 text-center" ng-if="isdataLoading">
        <cc-loading is-loading="isdataLoading" error="DataLoadirror"></cc-loading>
    </div>
</div>
```

`
============================ my-paged-data.html ==============================

```
<uib-pagination total-items="getTotalItemsCount()"
                max-size="pagingSettings.maxSize"
                first-text="<<"
                previous-text="<"
                next-text=">"
                last-text=">>"
                boundary-links="true"
                items-per-page="pagingSettings.recordsPerPage"
                ng-show="isPagingVisible()"
                ng-model="pageNumber"
                ng-change="setPage(pageNumber)">

</uib-pagination>
```

==========================================================================

Currently when I click the HTML table column header `Product` the `sortlist()` method in `table.js` is getting called, but the data in the table is not getting sorted unless I click the pagination tabs once. In the backend its getting sorted but `setPage(pageNumber)` needs to be called once (Its present in `my-paged-data.js` controller JS).

I want to somehow call the `setPage(pageNumber)` method that is present in the my-paged-data.js controller from inside the function `sortlist` which is present in the `table.js` file.

Is it possible ? If not then what approach shall I take to see the sorted data immediately when I click the column header by only making changes in `table.html` and `table.cs`.

Comment: Consider providing an intermediary means like a service, in which you then implement this `setPage(...)` function so that it can be called from where you need it to be.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9293423/can-one-angularjs-controller-call-another?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use the `prototypical inheritance` between Parent and Child Controller to solve this problem. In your case since the directive is called from table.html therefore following will be the hierarchy:

- Parent Controller: `table.js`
- Child Controller: `my-paged-data.js`

Finally, this is how your code should look like:

**table.js**

```
// Add this in the controller in the very start
$scope.forChild = {}

// Move the function of setPage to Parent Controller
$scope.forChild.setPage = function(pageNumber){...}

// Call the function
$scope.forChild.setPage(1)
```

**my-paged-data.html**

```
<uib-pagination total-items="getTotalItemsCount()"
                max-size="pagingSettings.maxSize"
                first-text="<<"
                previous-text="<"
                next-text=">"
                last-text=">>"
                boundary-links="true"
                items-per-page="pagingSettings.recordsPerPage"
                ng-show="isPagingVisible()"
                ng-model="pageNumber"
                ng-change="forChild.setPage(pageNumber)">

</uib-pagination>
```

Defining the function in parent-controller will give you the liberty to call it in child controller or parent controller whenever you want.